# Spring Integration w. JavaDSL - Dynamic RabbitMQ Routing Key

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I'm converting a Spring Integration application from XML to JavaDSL. The part I'm struggling with is the part that publishes a message to RabbitMQ. In the XML version the routing-key was extracted from the headers dynamically. However, in the JavaDSL version this does not work. To summarise, this works:

```
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="toRabbit" channel="rabbitChannel" amqp-template="rabbitMqTemplate"
                                       routing-key-expression="headers['routing-key']" exchange-name="invoice">
    </int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

This does not:

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow salesforceEventsFlow(MessageHandler messageHandler, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("rabbitChannel")
                .transform(messageHandler)
                .handle(m -> Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
                        .exchangeName("invoice")
                        .routingKey(m.getHeaders().get("routing-key").toString()))
                .get();
    }
```

Interestingly, having the routing key hardcoded works.

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow salesforceEventsFlow(MessageHandler messageHandler, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("rabbitChannel")
                .transform(messageHandler)
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
                        .exchangeName("invoice")
                        .routingKey("invoice.updated"))
                .get();
    }
```

How can I have dynamic routing keys when using JavaDSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use-case there is this configuration option:

```
/**
 * A function to evaluate routing key at runtime.
 * @param routingKeyFunction the {@link Function} to use.
 * @return the spec
 */
public S routingKeyFunction(Function<Message<?>, String> routingKeyFunction) {
```

So, your code should be like this:

```
.routingKeyFunction(m -> m.getHeaders().get("routing-key", String.class))
```

There is also a `routingKeyExpression()` if you want:

```
.routingKeyExpression("headers.routing-key")
```

But `Function` is better by performance: SpEL works with reflection.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks. I couldn't find any documentation on the available methods. Do you know if they are documented online anywhere please?

Comment: JavaDocs? IDE auto-completion? We definitely don’t do docs for every single bit in the code